# Can't install MFC Grid Control 2.27 into solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I added all the headers and sources as [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control) says. Then I included "GridCntrl.h" to the header, that conatins main form (CDialog). I also added custom control to the dialog box with "MFCGridControl" class name. But when I compile the project the app closes at the same time with 0 returned! Why not working?

Comment: Does your debugger refuse to work on fridays?

Comment: "when I compile the project the app closes"!? Sure?